# Is there a Xamarin Test Recorder For Windows?

Tags: windows, xamarin, xamarin.uitest

It is possible to run Xamarin Test Recorder on Windows 7?

I know that it support just OS X but im not sure that it can not run in Windows.

Do you Know some solution like Xamarin Test Recorder for windows?

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin have now released Xamarin UI Test recorder for Visual Studio.

First download the Visual Studio Extension from [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5839b0c2-42a5-439e-92b0-a533d10feda9)

Then follow the steps to Record a test in Visual Studio outlined [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/testrecorder/visual-studio/)

Answer (score 1):

As you said. It's only available for mac. So you have to run it on OS X. But you can write your tests in Visual Studio manually on Windows (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/quickstarts/android/). The test recorder is just a tool, that tries to make it easier. There is the REPL console that works on Windows. It helps you to find your views and evaluate your test code. And if you want to build a bigger, **maintainable** test suite, the test recorder output will not help much.

Comment: Thank you. I know that i can do it with Visual Studio and i do it. But i m looking for a fast way :)

Comment: REPL is pretty fast after some practice :> And as I said: Your initial effort may be lower, but the maintain effort will be higher. If you have no mac the only way is trying a VM or stay tuned for the Evolve in 15 days. There might be some updates (this is just speculative).

Comment: I have a solution i well just run a Mac virtual machine on windows

Comment: That's what I meant with "VM" ^^

Comment: Sorry I dont see your Reply

Answer (score 0):

Sadly Microsoft has discontinued development of Xamarin Test Recorder on macOS and the Visual Studio extension for Windows on March 31st, 2018. Upload to Test Cloud functionality from Xamarin Test Recorder will no longer be supported after this date. Moving forward tests must be submitted through the Visual Studio App Center CLI.